# Opencart image upload make filename safe

Tags: php, opencart

Using the opencart image manager how would I set the upload to automatically remove: spaces and un-safe characters from the image filename?

**Filemanager.php**

```
$filename = basename(html_entity_decode($this->request->files['image']['name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way would be to use a simple preg_replace such as

```
$filename = preg_replace('~[^\w\./\\\\]+~', '', $filename);
```

That will allow letters, numbers, underscore, back and forward slashes and a . in the filename only, and strip out anything else

Comment: html entity decode isn't required in the event of a file being uploaded

Comment: @JayGilford once again your knowledge of Opencart proceeds and impresses me. An asset to the OC Commerce Sphere Community. Repped.

Answer (score 0):

htmlspecialchars does exactly what needs to be done about unsafe characters, which are < > & ' " and nothing else.

```
      // for removing unsafe characters
       $text = htmlspecialchars($text);
```

// for removing whitespaces

With a regexp :

```
      preg_replace('/( )+/', ' ', $string);

      //If you also want to remove every multi-white characters, you can use \s (\s is  white characters)

      preg_replace('/(\s)+/', ' ', $string);
```